# "не люблю шутки" vs. "не люблю шуток"

Tags: падежи, родительный-падеж, винительный-падеж

I've noticed that verbs that normally take a direct object in Accusative quite often allow for Genitive, instead.

For example,

> исправлять ошибку (Accusative),
>
> but
>
> Вы уж, будьте добры, не исправляйте **ошибки** (Genitive) там, где её нет.

> любить шутки (Accusative),
>
> but
>
> Я не люблю **шуток** (Genitive).

> наснимать фильмы (Accusative),
>
> but
>
> **Таких фильмов** (Genitive) вам любой неопытный режиссёр сможет без труда наснимать.

Is there any general rule in Russian that regulates cases when direct objects can switch from Accusative to Genitive?

Comment: _Вы уж, будьте добры, не исправляйте ошибки (Genitive) там, где её нет._ is not correct. Either "**ошибку**", or "где **их** нет".

Comment: @Abakan - I kind of don't believe you that it's incorrect. Can you explain why it is not correct? What about "Будьте добры, не замечайте моей ошибки"? Is that also incorrect?

Comment: It's incorrect in the very same way as "мои книга" or "твоя одежды". "Будьте добры, не замечайте моей ошибки" is okay.

Comment: @Abakan - So why is "не замечайте моей ошибки" correct, but "не исправляйте (моей) ошибки" not?

Comment: I have no idea. BTW "не исправляйте моей ошибки" doesn't sound incorrect (but is a bit awkward), but "не исправляйте ошибки, там где ее нет" does.

Comment: @Abakan - Sorry, but I don't believe you here. It looks like it's just the way it sounds to you, but, unless you provide some valid proof, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's incorrect.

Comment: Come on, it's a basic level rule that transitive verbs can take direct objects in Genitive when the _verb is negated_. It's much like _У меня есть **деньги**._ vs. _У меня нет **денег**_, this SE has lots of questions about it: [When to use the genitive or the accusative in negative sentences](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/257/when-to-use-the-genitive-or-the-accusative-in-negative-sentences).

Comment: @YellowSky - But one of my examples (the last one) doesn't contain a negated verb. Thanks for the link, I am studying it now.

Comment: As for the example about films, my first thought was it's the Partitive Genitive case, like in _возьми **яблок**_ (Part. Gen. "some apples") vs. _возьми **яблоки**_ (Acc., "the apples"), but while I was writing my comment, the answer by @Quassnoi was posted, with an alternative explanation, so I decided to post the comment without mentioning the films sentence. I'm still thinking it over, and I'm inclined to think it's all about the verb _**на**снимать_, there are other (repetitive?) verbs with the prefix _на-_ that need Gen, object: _наделать делов_, _наломать дров_, etc.

Comment: The title example, "Я не люблю шуток" is somewhat idiomatic in Russian language. It means "I don't like when others try to trick/fool me" rather than "I don't like jokes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any general rule in Russian that regulates cases when direct objects can switch from Accusative to Genitive?

Not in a perfectly codified form, not that I know of.

Rosenthal has a whole chapter in his guide, called *Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием* which boils down to these three major cases:

> 1. Родительный падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение подчеркнутого отрицания.
>    …
> 2. Винительный падеж, ослабляющий значение отрицания.
>    …
> 3. Факультативное употребление родительного и винительного падежа при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со стилистическим различием: конструкции с родительным падежом характерны для книжной речи, конструкции с винительным падежом — для речи разговорной. Ср.: *Я не умаляю чьих-либо заслуг... (Горький). – Так и умрешь, не выговорив это слово (он же).*

Note that they are not prescriptive rules, they are just attempts to capture the patterns emerged in real life usage.

There are some clarifications which I think apply the most to your examples:

---

> Винительный падеж, ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется … при указании на конкретный объект: («именно этот предмет, а не вообще какой-то»): *не отрецензировал рукопись, которую ему прислали; не выпила молоко, которое ей оставила мать.* Например: *Он не отвергнул тогда с презрением эти сто рублей (Достоевский); Не наклоняй знамя-то… (Горький);*

If we treat it as an exception proving the rule, we can assume that abstract (and not concrete) nouns are used with genitive: *не исправляйте (эту) ошибку* vs. *не исправляйте ошибки (которой нет)*

However, there is another rule:

> при совпадении различных, но одинаково звучащих падежных форм для устранения неясности: *не читал сегодня газету* (форма *газеты* могла бы обозначать множественное число). Например: *…Дабы не поощрять в человеке чувство ростовщика (Горький)*

which tells us that the accusative is preferred in this case to resolve the ambiguity (which has been alluded to in the comments to the original question).

---

> Родительный падеж … употребляется в следующих случаях: … при глаголах восприятия, мысли, желания, ожидания (*видеть, слышать, понимать, думать, знать, хотеть, желать, ожидать* и т.п.), например: *Печали в ее словах Самгин не слышал (Горький); Он… деревни не знал (Чехов); Степка проглотил… конфеты и даже не заметил их вкуса (В. Гроссман);*

This I think applies to *я не люблю шуток*

---

Your third example is not a negation, but rather an ellipsis: *Таких фильмов вам любой неопытный режиссёр сможет без труда наснимать (сколько угодно)*.

However, this would require a genitive even without *таких*, because the verb belongs to the class of verbs with *на-* which govern the genitive:

> *на-*, глагольная приставка. Переходные глаголы с приставкой *на-*, выражающие полноту, количественное обилие в проявлении действия, управляют вин. и род. падежами, например: *надарить массу игрушек — надарить игрушек*. Форма род. падежа обычно употребляется, когда указывается распространение действия на неделимое вещество (*напустить дыму*) или на значительное количество из возможного множества предметов (*накупить книг*), а также если объектом действия является отвлеченное понятие (*наделать глупостей*). Название конкретного объекта ставится в форме вин. падежа, например: *налить стакан чаю* (ср. *налить чаю*), *нарвать букет цветов* (ср. *нарвать цветов*).

Comment: Would it be eligible to say: "Печаль в ее словах Самгин не слышал" or "Печаль в ее глазах Самгин не видел"? And if we put it up as: "В ее словах Самгин не слышал печаль" or "В ее глазах Самгин не видел печаль"?

Comment: @Eugene: I guess it would be ok if *печаль* were already in context (i. e. if it would have been used with "the" in English). Something like: *В её словах были гнев и раздражение, но не печаль. Печаль в её словах Самгин не слышал*.

Comment: More than intelligible answer, thank you.